# Understanding lie bracket of simple Lie algebra $W(2)$

Tags: lie-algebras

Please accept my apologies in advance for my simple question.

Let $W(2)$ be a simple Lie algebra over $\mathrm{GF}(2)$. We know that it has a basis with three elements like ${w_1,w_2,w_3}$. I cannot understand how to compute the Lie bracket for this Lie algebra? $[w_1,w_2]=?$ $[w_3,w_1]=?$

I have already studied the paper from B. Eick.(http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717110000805)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple Lie algebra $W(1; \underline{2})^{(1)}$ over $GF(2)$ has a basis $\{w_1,w_2,w_3 \}$ such that $[w_i,w_j]=w_k$, where $\{i,j,k\}=\{1,2,3\}$.

Answer (score 0):

This Lie algebra also arises in the classification of $3$-dimensional simple Lie algebras as follows:

*Theorem*: let $L$ be a simple, $3$-dimensional Lie algebra over an algebraically closed field of characteristic $2$. Then $L\simeq W(2)$.

If $e,f,h$ is a basis, then $[e,f]=h, [h,e]=e, [h,f]=f$. The Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$ in characteristic $2$ is isomorphic to the Heisenberg Lie algebra, so no longer simple. In a sense the replacement for it here is $W(2)=W(1;2)^{(1)}$.